# How Can I Ignore Safe Area When Adding Constraints to AR SceneKit View on iPhone X?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm making an app that uses AR SceneKit View but when I constrain to the edges of the phone on an iPhone 8, it doesn't take up the whole screen on the iPhone X. I think it is because of the safe area and I've been playing around with it for an hour now and can't figure out how to fix this.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm talking about:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHAeB.jpg

Sorry if this is a noob question this is my first time working in xcode

Comment: uncheck the safe area layout from your xib

Comment: @AsimIfitkharAbbasi , no Unchecking Safe area would is not a proper solution, as it wont allow other constraints to take safe area (where its really needed)

Answer (score 5):

Give its Constraint respect to view, instead of Safe-area, when you are giving constraint, there is small bottom arrow and select your choice from there. [image]